# Insufficient privileges when updating help files in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and I've downloaded the Visual Studio 2012 ISO from MSDN.
When trying to install the documentation:

I open Visual Studio as an Administrator

[image: Visual Studio Open As Admin]

Follow these instructions as per the install's ReadMe file

> On the menu bar for Visual Studio 2012, choose Help, Add and Remove
>   Help Content.
>
> Help Viewer 2.0 starts, showing the Manage Content tab.
>   On the Manage Content tab, choose the Disk option button, choose the
>   Browse (…) button, and then navigate to the DVD drive.
>
> Choose the helpcontentsetup.msha file, and then choose the Open button.
>
> Under Available Documentation, the list of available content sets from the
>   DVD appears.
>
> Choose the Add link next to the content set that you want
>   to install onto your local computer. 
>   The items that you specify appear
>   in the Pending Changes column. You can remove an item from the Pending
>   Changes column by choosing the “X” next to the item. 
>   Choose the Update button.

[image: Update Ready]

And click Update.

When I click Update, it progresses for about 3-4 seconds, and then it fails with an error:

> The following errors occurred while performing the requested tasks:
>
> An error occurred while updating content. You have insufficient
>   privileges to complete this task.

[image: insufficient privileges]

How can I resolve this issue?

**Update**

I'm running Help Viewer in Admin mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this. It solved my problem.

1. change security permission of vs2012doc.iso to full control for your account.
2. Mount it
3. Install the documentation ONE BY ONE. Remember ONE BY ONE.

Might it help...

Answer (score 0):

Change your machine date and try again. In my case work with "oct/01/2012".

Answer (score 0):

This was using the Visual Studio 2013 but is likely to be similar to the help of Visual Studio 2012 and probably 2015. I have not tried it so you tell me.

I got the ISO with the help of vs2013 to Microsoft directly. Now I do not remember the address so I did not put it here. It is very easy to get around with google looking for.

When I'm using the Microsoft Help Viewer 2.1 with local installation way I get an error: Insufficient Privileges and not the books are installed.

What I will describe is possible for you to do so more easily. But I could not validate it and then they describe the steps I followed to do so.

The first thing I did was copy the entire contents of the ISO to a folder on my HDD for my comfort my case was in `C:\T`

With the command prompt navigate to the folder where it was copied from the iso content and the `C:\T\Packages`run the following `winrar t * .cab`

This causes a test winrar make all cab files and protest whenever any of them is corrupt.

This was to score those files that had to go down again, in my case only had a .cab file with problems

**v2Visual_Studio_2011_NET_Framework_4_B1545_VS_100_en-us_13(b0ba5cce-2b72-f582-80f3-8a6165ef6b9b).cab**

The following was download it directly from Microsoft in this direction,
 
http://packages.mtps.microsoft.com/v2Visual_Studio_2011_NET_Framework_4_B1545_VS_100_en-us_13(b0ba5cce-2b72-f582-80f3-8a6165ef6b9b).cab

All other packages I think are there too.

The next thing was to replace the damaged file with the new and final step is to go into the folder where the files of the Visual Studio Help are, in my case I always use to put this folder in a comfortable place for me.

```
D:\VS_2012_2013_HLP\VisualStudio12
```

Inside this folder there are other two `\Incoming\Cab`, we must ensure that the cab folder is completely empty.

The last thing is to enter the Microsoft Help Viewer 2.1 and say that the new power plant is one where we copy the contents of the ISO (`D:\T\helpcontentsetup.msha`). The rest is just install the books ..